# shell script to excute c++ program in parallel to different machine without asking password

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I need to write shell script to execute c++ program in centos linux multiple machine parallel  without asking password,so can I write please help me thanks for your response.

I am try to write like this but this is not parallel and asking password

```
#!/bin/sh
    (
        ssh oracle@172.20.2.147 "/oracle/Desktop/analysis/engine"#machine1
        ssh oracle@172.20.2.146 "/home/storage/Desktop/storage/storage"#machine2
        ssh oracle@172.20.2.148 "/home/oracle/Desktop/agregete/collection"#machine3
        )
the 3 executable files are engine,storage and collection respectively
```

each execute sequentially and ask password, but I need paralyze and execute without asking password

Comment: As for the password issue, why not distribute your public key to the systems you want to log in to?

Comment: For the other issue, you do know how to run commands in the background?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how can i perform that thanks for your responce

Comment: @JoachimPileborg no just i am trying to run using this script

Comment: Regarding the key and login issue, that's more a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/tour). For the other issue, try to find a simple shell tutorial.

Comment: Take a look at SSH keys. http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Yes passwordless ssh can be easily performed if you know the set of machines on which you want to run your program before hand and you have access to all those machines prior to running your program. Google 'passwordless ssh' and you'll see links to set it up.

Comment: Simply researching the two problems would have led to an answer quite quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your response password using public key fixed .What about parallel execution three executed file are infinite loop so i have to use parallel execution so how?give me simple example based on my interest please.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned this is actually a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). But in order to provide you with an answer, I think the solution for your problem should be [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/318474/how-to-pass-password-to-scp-command-used-in-bash-script). This solution works the same way for ssh as it does for scp. A better way though would be using public keys as Joachim Pileborg has already pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for your response what about parallel executing those executed file each of them infinite while loop please focus on the parallel execution thank all of you about password issue.

Comment: My bad. If you require to handle your stuff simultaneously you should consider using sth. like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). Depending on the number of servers you want to manage and the complexity of the tasks you want to process you could also check out [Salt](http://saltstack.com/).